# tcolorbox, only align the left part of a divided box

Tags: tcolorbox, alignment

I'm trying to use the ams equation* alignment, but only on the left part, ie upper part of my box.

```
\newtcolorbox{outerBoxDef}[1]{
   halign=center, breakable, enhanced, colback=black!5!white, colframe=black!75!white,
   title={Définition : {\bf #1}}
}

\newtcolorbox{twocolBoxDef}{
   halign=center, sidebyside, sidebyside align=top, enhanced, arc=0pt, colback=black!5!white, colframe=black!75!white,
   boxsep=1mm, notitle, oversize, nobeforeafter, frame hidden,
   ams equation* % <------ here
}

\begin{outerBoxDef}{Nombre de Knudsen}
\begin{twocolBoxDef}
\begin{align*}
   \boldsymbol{K_n = \dfrac{l}{L}}
\end{align*}
\tcblower
$l$ le libre parcours moyen\\ \\
$L$ une distance caractéristique de l'échelle macroscopique
\end{twocolBoxDef}
Le libre parcours moyen est la distance parcourue par une particule entre deux chocs consécutifs.
\end{outerBoxDef}
```

Does that :
[image]

How can I only align the left part of the box?

Comment: Please, next time, try to provide a minimal but complete example, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`. It will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\newtcolorbox{outerBoxDef}[1]{
   halign=center, breakable, enhanced, colback=black!5!white, colframe=black!75!white,
   title={Définition : {\bf #1}}
}

\newtcolorbox{twocolBoxDef}{
   halign=center, sidebyside, sidebyside align=top, enhanced, arc=0pt, colback=black!5!white, colframe=black!75!white,
   boxsep=1mm, notitle, oversize, nobeforeafter, frame hidden,
%   ams equation upper* % <------ here
}

\begin{document}

\begin{outerBoxDef}{Nombre de Knudsen}
\begin{twocolBoxDef}
\begin{align*}
   \boldsymbol{K_n = \dfrac{l}{L}}
\end{align*}
\tcblower
$l$ le libre parcours moyen\\ \\
$L$ une distance caractéristique de l'échelle macroscopique
\end{twocolBoxDef}
Le libre parcours moyen est la distance parcourue par une particule entre deux chocs consécutifs.
\end{outerBoxDef}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case that this is not what you want, try with other options like `ams equation upper`, `ams align upper`, ... (pp 388-390)

Comment: It does look good, but I don't want the text in the outer box to be centered.

Comment: @ituriel Therefore, why do you use `halign=center`?

Comment: sorry, I meant I want to use the full width of the box. Your text is split before it comes to the end of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a solution : I added an invisible character above my equation and remove the `ams equation*` option. It doens't look bad :

```
\newtcolorbox{outerBoxDef}[1]{
  halign=center, breakable, enhanced, colback=black!5!white, colframe=black!75!white,
  title={Définition : {\bf #1}}
}
\newtcolorbox{twocolBoxDef}{ halign=center, sidebyside, sidebyside align=top, enhanced, arc=0pt, colback=black!5!white, colframe=black!75!white, boxsep=1mm, notitle, oversize, nobeforeafter, frame hidden,
}

\begin{outerBoxDef}{Nombre de Knudsen}
\begin{twocolBoxDef}
\hphantom{a}\\
$\boldsymbol{K_n = \dfrac{l}{L}}$
\tcblower
$l$ le libre parcours moyen\\\\
$L$ une distance caractéristique de l'échelle macroscopique
\end{twocolBoxDef}
Le libre parcours moyen est la distance parcourue par une particule entre deux chocs consécutifs.
\end{outerBoxDef}
```

[image]